# Sql prevent duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a  MySql table named "service":

```
*Table Service*
PK serv_ID  Int(2)
Address Varchar(20)
Date Date
```

Than I have a table name "materials":

```
*Table Materials*
 PK Mat_ID Int(2)
 Stock_Qty Int(2)
 Unit enum(m,u)
```

Now, for each service, I spent some materials and I've made a table:

```
Service_Material
FK serv_ID
Fk Mat_ID 
Qty int(2)
```

How can I prevent for each service, don't repeat the same material?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a unique constraint or index:

```
create unique index unq_service_material_serv_mat on service_material(serv_id, mat_id);
```

You can also add this as a constraint (instead):

```
alter table service_material
    add constraint unq_service_material_serv_mat
        unique(serv_id, mat_id);
```